# Understanding quadratic order of convergence - Taylor Expansion

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

Can anyone explain how to get from line A to line B? The absolute values signs are throwing me off.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about why the second limit in $A$ is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lim a_n=a$ then also $\lim |a_n|=|a|$. You are interested in the version with absolute values since that is the form in the definition of the convergence order. The sign information that you lose from the previous computation plays no role in the convergence order, but might be useful in a quick plausibility check of numerical results.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So how do I know, from line B, that the order of convergence is 2? I feel like it's so simple - but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Yes, as $|e_n|\le C|E_{n-1}|^2$ implies $C|e_n|\le (C|e_0|)^{2^n}$ which roughly translates into the usual doubling of significant digits in each step.